# Visual Recogntition App - Assistance

Tags: git, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, visual-recognition

I need feedback on the following.  I am attempting to create a visual recognition app using Bluemix,,  I am using the CF command line to push my app after I make any changes
 I am  stuck. and need your guidance on how to :

1). Properly Add the pictures  to the code -  so that they can finally appear on the visual recognition app page
2.) Ultimately have a custom Classifier called " Mike Meaden Team "   So that when I choose any one of these pictures (that I need to properly load) will  Display the following images  and names under Mike Meaden Team classification , having the picture display with the persons name and description of duties.

Currently the positive and negative images that I attempted to load onto the code , these pictures do not appear on the web app page, nor do they display in Bluemix Images dataset (files code section) I must be doing something wrong

Please provide me any guidance. I am basing the creation of the app solely on the documentation, I haven´t used Blue mix in the past and my programming skills are at beginner stage,

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks,.

http://michael-meaden-team.mybluemix.net/

Comment: Please provide more information - how are you configuring your visual recognition app? What code are you using to attempt to load the images? Stack Overflow is a forum for specific coding questions; if you have additional questions about getting started with the Bluemix platform and any of the services, the best place for those is IBM developerWorks Answers (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smartspace/bluemix/)

Comment: I am using http://michael-meaden-team.mybluemix.net/

Comment: I am using the CF cloud foundry command line to push my app after I make any changes, using Brackets and notepad++ to edit code.
 I am  stuck. and need your guidance on how to :1). Properly Add the pictures  to the code.
2.) results have a Classifier called " Mike Meaden Team "   So that when I choose any pictures that I load (need to properly load) will  Display the names under Mike Meaden Team classification , having the picture display with the persons name and description of duties

 App website http://michael-meaden-team.mybluemix.net/

Comment: you may find this somewhat useful https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/estimate-a-childs-age-based-on-photos-using-watson-visual-recognition/